# a problem in exact sequence

Tags: modules, exact-sequence, abstract-algebra

> Suppose
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     @.\acute M @>f>> M @>g>>\check M @>>> O\\
>     @. @V \alpha V V\ @VV \beta V @VV \gamma V @. \\
> O@>>> \acute N @>\phi>> N @>\omega>> \check N @. 
>     \end{CD}
>   is commutative diagram from $R$-modules and $R$-homomorphisms, s.t. every row is exact sequence.
>   How To Prove this row is exact sequence:
>   $\require{AMScd}$
>   \begin{CD}
>     Ker \alpha @>\check f>> Ker\beta @>>>Ker\gamma @>d>> \frac{\acute N}{Im \alpha}
> @>>> \frac{N}{Im \alpha} @>\check \omega >> \frac{\check N}{Im \alpha}\\
>  \end{CD}
>   also : if $f$ is one-one function then $\check f$is one-one function,and if $\omega$ is onto function then $\check \omega$ is onto function.

it's my effort:
we have: $Imf=Ker g=ker O$ ,$ImO=Ker \phi=Im\omega$ by (every rows is exact sequence)

$\phi \alpha=\beta f,,\omega \beta=\gamma g$ by (is commutative diagram)
we must find 5 function s.t. $Im\phi_{i-1}=Ker\phi_i$
also we have "short five lemma" (perhaps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernels go in a row above the diagram, and the cokernels go in the row below. The trickiest part of the exact sequence you need is in the middle. To construct the map $d$ one must watch this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etbcKWEKnvg